# else statement not retuning values

Tags: javascript, typescript, conditional-operator

In my code, I'm checking for `window` and `window['cid_global']` if any one of them is undefined,

I wanted to return **{brand: 'unknown', locale: {country: '', language: ''}, ENV: '', accessPath: '', contrastPreference: '' }** to `cid_global`.

But it returns as `undefined`.

What I'm doing wrong here ?

stackBliz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-7d1urh

```
const isClient = typeof window;
const isCidGlobal = typeof window['cid_global'];

const _window = isClient !== undefined ? window : {};

const cid_global = (_window !== undefined && isCidGlobal !== undefined)? _window['cid_global'] : {brand: 'unknown', locale: {country: '', language: ''}, ENV: '', accessPath: '', contrastPreference: '' };

console.log(isCidGlobal) // undefined;
console.log(cid_global) // should return object instead of undefined;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`typeof`'s result is a **string**. You're comparing it to the value `undefined`. You need to compare it with the *string* `"undefined"`.

I'd also move that check so that your variables with flag-like names (`isClient`, `isCidGlobal`) are actually flags, rather than strings. Also, if `window` isn't defined, your second line will fail because you try to use `undefined['cid_global']`.

So for instance:

```
const isClient = typeof window !== "undefined";
// *** −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^−−−−−−−−−^
const isCidGlobal = isClient && typeof window['cid_global'] !== "undefined";
// *** −−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

const _window = isClient ? window : {}; // ** Removed the comparison

// *** Replaced everything before the ? with just `isCidGlobal`
const cid_global = isCidGlobal ? _window['cid_global'] : {brand: 'unknown', locale: {country: '', language: ''}, ENV: '', accessPath: '', contrastPreference: '' };
```

But unless you're using it for something else, you don't need `_window`:

```
const isClient = typeof window !== "undefined";
const isCidGlobal = isClient && typeof window['cid_global'] !== "undefined";
const cid_global = isCidGlobal ? window['cid_global'] : {brand: 'unknown', locale: {country: '', language: ''}, ENV: '', accessPath: '', contrastPreference: '' };
```

Or, again unless you're using it for something else, `isCidGlobal`:

```
const isClient = typeof window !== "undefined";
const isCidGlobal = (isClient && window['cid_global']) || {brand: 'unknown', locale: {country: '', language: ''}, ENV: '', accessPath: '', contrastPreference: '' };
```

(Granted, that version assumes `window['cid_global']` isn't some other falsy value, but it looks like a safe assumption.)

Comment: Or eventually, directly  `window['cid_global'] !== undefined`

Comment: @Cid - Yeah, once you know `window` exists, you can do that.

Comment: Note: There were a couple of `===`s that should have been `!==`s. I've fixed them now.